# Indy 10 fails to install into Delphi 5

Tags: delphi, installation, indy10, delphi-5, failed-installation

I have Delphi 10 Seattle, but I have an older program I wrote in 1995 with Delphi 1. I have since moved it to Delphi 5 — because of all the old 3rd-party components I have used over the years, it would be a total re-write (at least a year) to move it into Delphi 10 Seattle.

One of my secure websites the program uses is soon going to require TLS 1.2. I have Indy 9 installed, and that has worked fine with TLS 1.0, but I understand the only way for TLS 1.2 is to install Indy 10. So far, I have been unsuccessful.

1. I followed the instructions to the word using the batch file method after removing any instance of Indy 9 (mainly renaming files and directories in case of the worse scenario).
2. I changed my Environment path to the correct D2 folder Indy's batch file created.
3. I installed both of the dclIndyCore50 and dclIndyProtocols50 BPL's in the package installer.
4. They both go in and are checked (enabled). Components were visible.
5. Then I exit Delphi 5 and either get the following error or the 2 packages are unchecked:

   [image: Error Message]

I have tried to move the all the files from the created 'D2' folder to a folder right off of my C drive in case it was some sort of Windows 10 permission problem. I changed environment paths to match and add those packages. Still, Delphi states it can't find the file.

Installation seems simple enough. What could I be doing wrong? I left a post in the Tools section of Embarcadero's forum, but I can see it is not used much. Search the forum and found '0' results. I sure how your Delphi experts can help.

Comment: What are you read/write permissions for the folder in which those BPL's are stored? Since Delphi 5 predates UAC I guess the UAC might be blocking access to those files if Delphi is trying to open them in rewrite mode. So try launching Delphi with elevated privileges (Run as Administrator) or changing read/write permissions to that folder to see if the problem still persists.

Comment: First, Indy's batch script does not create a `D2` folder, it creates a `D5` folder (assuming you are running `fulld_5.bat`). Second, the error can be a bit misleading, as it may mean a dependent BPL is missing, rather than the dcl BPL itself. `dclIndyCore50.bpl` depends on the `IndySystem50.bpl` and `IndyCore50.bpl` runtime packages, so make sure they exist on the search path correctly.  Use a tool like [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to find out *exactly* which file is actually missing and where the OS it looking for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delphi 5 likes to see BPL related files in his directory.
(Of course you have to adapt the path specified in this example.)

Search for the **Indy*.* files, copy all with the same compilation date/time to Delphi5's folder.   Look at next picture for the path and files.

[image]

If you have the files !! (Don't copy now first) Remove the previous assignment to the Component.
Press Remove to

```
Indy 10 Core Desig Time -> dclIndyCore50.bpl
Indy 10 Protocols Design Time -> dclIndyProtocols50.bpl
```

[image]

Close and Restart Delphi

*Now copy the files to the Delphi folder!*

Install Component Package

[image]

press **Add** (look at Image above)
goto `...\Delphi5\Projects\Bpl\dclIndyCore50.bpl`
next Add  `...\Delphi5\Projects\Bpl\dclIndyProtocols50.bpl`

Make sure that the path to Delphi is in Environment

`F:\Programme\Borland\Delphi5\bin;F:\Programme\Borland\Delphi5\Projects\Bpl;`

Close and restart Delphi.

Comment: Well, I did get it working by copying only the BPL files to the projects/bpl folder and it did let me add the two design bpl files to he the pagkages without an error. But I will copy the rest as it might solve my next problem.

The only reason for going to Indy 10 was to make available TLS 1.2, but when dropping a SSL (what ever it is called now) to the form, it crashes Delphi. Maybe adding all the files as you suggested will keep that from happening.

I

Comment: @RobertGriffinrealsol : And now ? How long can it take to copy all files ? 2 Days ?

Comment: Sorry. Been out of town for 2 days.,but D5 still insisted I include the actual source path also.

There are some events,methods and procedure changes I will have to deal with (I'm not on my development machine) but like HTTP.DoProsses doesn't work. But do to your post I was actually able to get all the design components installed, though some, when dropped on a new project crashes Delphi 5 with no real explanation. I am going to dive deeper on Monday. Do you know of a web page that will show discontinued events and methods and what replaced them in Indy 10?

Comment: @RobertGriffinrealsol : sorry this Questions is about `Indy 10 fails to install into Delphi 5` .To help other user you should check this answer as answered. Please ask a new question with the new come in problem!

Comment: Sorry about that. Actually, I do like that as some forums get so off topic. moskito-x did answer my questions and I did get Indy 10 installed but have other Indy 10 problems. I will start a new Question. But I am not sure how to mark this question as answered.

Comment: ***** Deleted *****